# VBA ArcGIS 9.3 Field Calculator: 'countif' across several fields

Tags: arcgis-9.3, field-calculator, vba

I have an attribute table with 15 columns that contain either a '0' or a taxonomy number. I would like a summarized column that shows the number of different species.

```
location  type1  type2  type3  etc etc...  nr_of_species
    1      123    234    0      .........      2
    2      456     0     0      .........      1
    3       0      0     0      .........      0
```

Is there a way to do this with VBA and field calculator? I have no experience with VBA, so i might need a complete dummy-guide.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I solved it with writing really ugly code:

```
Dim counter as integer
counter = 0

if [type1] > 0 then
    counter = counter + 1
endif
if [type2] > 0 then
    counter = counter + 1
endif
```

etc etc..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you've done it, some logic can often be verbose. More importantly it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use Python, you could do this in the Field Calculator...

In the "Pre-logic script code" box:

```
def CountFieldsGreaterThanZero(fieldList):
  counter = 0
  for field in fieldList:
    if field > 0:
      counter += 1
  return counter
```

In the expression box:

```
CountFieldsGreaterThanZero([!type1!, !type2!, !type3!, !type4!])
```

Essentially what you do is pass a "list of fields" (surrounded by brackets) that you want to  evaulate to the CountFieldsGreaterThanZero function...